# How to use horizontal "material progressindicator" in android?

Tags: android, material-design, android-progressbar, material-components-android, material-components

I've used "android.material.progressindicator" for the purpose of showing progress in horizontal view but I can't hear my XML

```
<com.google.android.material.progressindicator.ProgressIndicator
                android:background="@color/grey"
                android:id="@+id/progressInd"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.ProgressIndicator.Linear.Determinate"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:indeterminate="false"
                android:max="100"
                android:progress="30"
                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/bidding_progress" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use:

```
<com.google.android.material.progressindicator.LinearProgressIndicator
    app:indicatorColor="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:trackColor="@color/..."
    />
```

Use `progressIndicator.setProgressCompat((int) value, true);` to update the value in the indicator.

Use the attributes:

- `indicatorColor` to se the color of the color of indicator
- `trackColor` to set the color of track
- `trackThickness`  to set the height of the progress bar

[image]

**Note:** It **requires** at least the version `1.3.0-alpha04`

Comment: In SDK Version 25 I run that application. App crash. Logcat message following as "Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.drawable.Drawable com.google.android.material.progressindicator.ProgressIndicator.getCurrentDrawable() would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ProgressBar" but this code runs on SDK 28. Please give me your suggestions to slove this issue.

Comment: @RaJ you can file an issue on the [github repo](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android).

Comment: Ok thanks. Initially, I've set progressIndicator.setMin(0); now I remove that line now working fine.

Comment: For indetermined: `
    android:indeterminate="true"`