# How to set `LinearProgressIndicator`'s height in a `MotionLayout` scene?

Tags: android, android-motionlayout

I use a `LinearProgressIndicator` inside a `MotionLayout` that I would like its height to vary from default value to 0. Setting `layout_height` doesn't change the progress bar's height at all. According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62219161/3459089), `trackThickness` is the way to go. But setting this value in the scene doesn't change the `LinearProgressIndicator`'s height.

Here is what I tried:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

  <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
    <Constraint android:id="@id/now_playing_progress">
      <CustomAttribute
        motion:attributeName="trackThickness"
        motion:customDimension="?attr/trackThickness"
      />
    </Constraint>
  </ConstraintSet>

  <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
    <Constraint android:id="@id/now_playing_progress">
      <CustomAttribute
        motion:attributeName="trackThickness"
        motion:customDimension="0dp"
      />
    </Constraint>
  </ConstraintSet>

  <Transition
    motion:constraintSetEnd="@id/end"
    motion:constraintSetStart="@+id/start"
  >
    
  </Transition>
</MotionScene>
```

*Edit:* the code I tried from [C.F.G](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6576302/c-f-g)'s solution:

```xml
<!-- Layout -->

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

  <merge>
    <!-- Placeholder for setting constraints and interacting -->
    <View
      android:id="@+id/constraint_layout_placeholder"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    />

    <com.google.android.material.progressindicator.LinearProgressIndicator
      android:id="@+id/now_playing_progress"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/constraint_layout_placeholder"
      android:progress="@{progress, default=40}"
      android:progressTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    />

    <!-- Snip -->
  </merge>
</layout>

<!-- Scene -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

  <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
    <Constraint android:id="@id/constraint_layout_placeholder">
      <PropertySet android:visibility="visible" />
    </Constraint>
  </ConstraintSet>

  <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
    <Constraint
      android:id="@id/now_playing_progress"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      motion:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0"
      motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    <Constraint android:id="@id/constraint_layout_placeholder">
      <PropertySet android:visibility="invisible" />
    </Constraint>
  </ConstraintSet>

  <Transition
    motion:constraintSetEnd="@id/end"
    motion:constraintSetStart="@+id/start"
    >
  </Transition>
</MotionScene>
```

Comment: Try this: add 
            `android:layout_height="0dp"
            motion:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"` to `<Constraint `

Comment: I'm sorry, that doesn't work. The progress bar is still there.

Comment: paste your implemented code (what I said in previous comment) here.

Comment: I edited the question. Note that I don't really understand what `motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"` and `motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"` are for but they mess up the layout. I end up with a huge blank space above the `LinearProgressIndicator`

Comment: Change `<layout` to `<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout` and add `app:layoutDescription="@xml/your_motion_scene"` to it.

Comment: Hmm… No. This is a partial that is included in another layout using `<include>`. The `MotionLayout` is elsewhere. All the other animations a working correctly. There's just the `LinearProgressIndicator` whose I can't change height.

Comment: But you haven't said that. Try to set height close to zero and not equal to zero. E.g. `height="1dp"`. Because `0dp` in constraint Layout means _fill it as much as it is possible_